# Import path in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, python-import

I have Python Flask project with following structure of my project (I removed uneccesary things):

```
server
    src
        service
            __init__.py
            User.py
    tests
        pytest.ini
        service
            test_user.py
```

Where `pytest.ini` contains:

```
[pytest]
python_paths = ../src
```

And `test_user.py`:

```
from service.User import UserService

def test_empty_db():
    service = UserService()
    users = service.get_all()  # Get all users from DB.
    assert len(users) = 0  # There should be users.
```

Now, I would like to run this test. When I run `pytest` or `pytest server` from root of project, everything is ok. However, when I want to run the specified file `pytest server/tests/service/test_user.py` error appears:

> from services.User import UserService
> E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'service'

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make your imports more absolute inside your `test_user.py` like: `from server.src.service.User import …`

Or you can also try adding a `__init__.py` to your tests directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is showing `services.User` while you code is showing `service.User`, could it be a typo?